# Ошибка при сборке UNITY - More than one file was found with OS independent path

Tags: unity3d, android-studio, gradle

Суть ошибки:

`More than one file was found with OS independent path 'kotlin/collections/MapWithDefault.kotlin_metadata'`

Добавление **SDK** в последний раз `Facebook Analytics` привело кучу проблем лично для меня, при билде выходят данные ошибки:

```
What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':launcher:mergeReleaseJavaResource'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
 > More than one file was found with OS independent path 'kotlin/collections/MapWithDefault.kotlin_metadata'
```

Где `A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade` именно окно при билде выходит с данной ошибкой.

Но я также уверен что именно данная строка мешает всему `More than one file was found with OS independent path 'kotlin/collections/MapWithDefault.kotlin_metadata'`

Мой gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'

// Android Resolver Dependencies Start
    implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0+' // Assets/Plugins/VoxelBusters/CrossPlatformReplayKit/Editor/ReplayKitDependencies.xml:6
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1' // Facebook.Unity.Editor.AndroidSupportLibraryResolver.addSupportLibraryDependency
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1' // Facebook.Unity.Editor.AndroidSupportLibraryResolver.addSupportLibraryDependency
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:25.3.1' // Facebook.Unity.Editor.AndroidSupportLibraryResolver.addSupportLibraryDependency
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1' // Facebook.Unity.Editor.AndroidSupportLibraryResolver.addSupportLibraryDependency
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-applinks:[11.0, 12)' // Assets/FacebookSDK/Plugins/Editor/Dependencies.xml:6
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-core:[11.0, 12)' // Assets/FacebookSDK/Plugins/Editor/Dependencies.xml:5
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-gamingservices:[11.0, 12)' // Assets/FacebookSDK/Plugins/Editor/Dependencies.xml:9
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[11.0, 12)' // Assets/FacebookSDK/Plugins/Editor/Dependencies.xml:7
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-share:[11.0, 12)' // Assets/FacebookSDK/Plugins/Editor/Dependencies.xml:8
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.0.0' // Assets/GoogleMobileAds/Editor/GoogleMobileAdsDependencies.xml:7
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.6.0' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/AppDependencies.xml:17
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:19.0.0' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/AppDependencies.xml:15
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-unity:8.0.0' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/AnalyticsDependencies.xml:18
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-app-unity:8.0.0' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/AppDependencies.xml:22
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-common:20.0.0' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/AppDependencies.xml:13
    implementation 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.4.0' // Assets/FacebookSDK/Plugins/Editor/Dependencies.xml:4
    implementation 'com.tapjoy:tapjoy-android-unitybridge:12.8.1' // Assets/Tapjoy/Editor/TJPluginDependencies.xml:9
// Android Resolver Dependencies End
**DEPS**}

// Android Resolver Exclusions Start
android {
  packagingOptions {
      pickFirst 'kotlin/collections/MapWithDefault.kotlin_metadata'
      exclude ('/lib/armeabi/*' + '*')
      exclude ('/lib/mips/*' + '*')
      exclude ('/lib/mips64/*' + '*')
      exclude ('/lib/x86/*' + '*')
      exclude ('/lib/x86_64/*' + '*')
  }
}
// Android Resolver Exclusions End
android {
    compileSdkVersion **APIVERSION**
    buildToolsVersion '**BUILDTOOLS**'

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        minSdkVersion **MINSDKVERSION**
        targetSdkVersion **TARGETSDKVERSION**
        ndk {
            abiFilters **ABIFILTERS**
        }
        versionCode **VERSIONCODE**
        versionName '**VERSIONNAME**'
        consumerProguardFiles 'proguard-unity.txt'**USER_PROGUARD**
    }
}
```

Как видно я использовал для решения проблемы:

```
pickFirst 'kotlin/collections/MapWithDefault.kotlin_metadata'
```

Но и я использовал

```
exclude 'kotlin/collections/MapWithDefault.kotlin_metadata'
```

Что тоже не помогло. Какие ещё могут быть решения?

Comment: а вы уверены, что вам нужна Facebook Analytics в проекте? ее поддержка прекращена с 1ого июля

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После очень долгого поиска, я пришёл к решению:

Я правильно загружал всё в `gradle`, только не в тот. Я загружал в `custom mainTemplate.gradle`, ничего не менялось, поиски меня привели к ещё одному `gradle` это `launcherTemplate.gradle`, эти `gradle` свели меня с ума.

Достаточно перенести необходимые зависимости с `mainTemplate` в `launcherTemplate`, как всё начинает работать.

Зависимости которые были нужны в данной ошибке:

```
exclude ('kotlin/*' + '*') // для всех kotlin зависимостей
exclude ('META-INF/*' + '*') // для всех META-INF зависимостей
```

И мне необходимо было также перенести туда же мои

```
multidex = true
```

и

```
implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
```

*Как включить `gradle` файлы:*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Надеюсь кому то мой ответ будет очень полезен, и сохранит чье-то дорогое время.